# jeditable propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable, event-propagation

i'm using jeditable and I have nested elements all binded to jeditable. Problem is when I click on a nested element the click event gets triggered on the top most parent. How can I avoid this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log('loading');
 $('div.wrapper').editable('edit/', { 
     loadurl   : 'edit/',
     //id        : 'section',
     name      : 'content',
     submitdata  : function(value, settings) {
         var section = $(this).parent('section').attr("data-section");
         return {
             section: section,
             type: 'ajax',
         }
     },
     loaddata  : function(value, settings) {
         var section = $(this).parent('section').attr("data-section");
         return {
             section: section,
             type: 'ajax',
         }
     },
     rows      : 6,
     width     : '100%',
     type      : 'textarea',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'OK',
     indicator : 'Saving changes',
     tooltip   : "Doubleclick to edit...",
     onblur    : 'ignore',
     event     : "dblclick",
     style     : 'inherit',
     callback : function(value, settings) {
         // console.log(this);
         console.log(value);
         console.log(settings);
         $('section[class^="annotation"]').each(function(index) {
            $(this).attr('data-section', index + 1);
         });
     }
 });
});
```

[edit]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<article>
    <section class="annotation1" data-section="1" id="section_data-section1" typeof="aa:section">
        <div class="wrapper" title="Doubleclick to edit...">
            <h1>Section </h1>
            <p>some content</p>
            <section class="annotation2" data-section="2" id="subsection_data-section2" typeof="aa:section">
                <div class="wrapper" title="Doubleclick to edit...">
                    <h2>Subsection </h2>
                    <p>some more content</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</article>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code?

Comment: could you provide your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is trickier than I originally thought...

Firstly, you could handle the `.dblclick` event for the `div.wrapper`, so you can stop event propagation. At each double-click, you attach the jEditable to the element and trigger it (note the `.click()` after calling `.editable()`. After finish editing the element, destroy the jEditable element.

While I was thinking it was the end of it, something trickier came up. When finishing editing the outer `div.wrapper` element, the `dblclick` event in the inner `div.wrapper` disappeared! So, the `div.wrapper` element has to be cloned before it becomes an editable element. And just after the jEditable restores the wrapper element, it is replaced with the previously stored clone.

```
$('div.wrapper').dblclick(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    // save a clone of "this", including all events and data
    $(this).data('clone', $(this).clone(true, true))
        .editable('edit/', {
        onreset: function() {
            var $that = this.parent();
            $that.editable('destroy');

            // restore the editable element with the clone
            // to retain the events and data
            setTimeout(function() {
                $that.replaceWith($that.data('clone'));
            }, 50);
        }
    }).click();
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/vmdz6/3/.

You may need to manually update the cloned element after it is updated with the edited data. You should be able to do that in the `callback` function.

Comment: Hi William and thanks for your help. I opened an issue there: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/issues/48 cause it seems to me a buggy behaviour. What do you think?

Comment: What is buggy about it? It is just that, jEditable does not allow users to manipulate event propagation, hence you need to control the event propagation yourself.